# ProgressDialog не отображает прогресс

Tags: android

Я использую простой пример использования ProgressDialog, вот он:

```
    ProgressDialog barProgressDialog;
  Handler updateBarHandler;

public void launchBarDialog() {
barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

barProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Image ...");
barProgressDialog.setMessage("Download in progress ...");
barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
barProgressDialog.setMax(20);
barProgressDialog.show();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      // Here you should write your time consuming task...
      while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            barProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(2);
          }
        });
        if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
          barProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}).start();
```

}

Автор этого фрагмента кода утверждает, что работает он правильно, прогресс отображается корректно. Но в моем проекте значение прогресса всегда находится в значении 0! Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `updateBarHandler` нигде не инициализируется. А все исключения выловите в:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

У вас просто эксепшн выскакиваетя на строке:

```
updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
```